# Team Foundation Server 2010: Other Users Not Seeing Changed Team Queries

Tags: tfs-workitem

My setup is Team Foundation Server 2010. We have some shared Work Item Queries. My question: When I edit a Team Query, other users do not get my changes. I suspect that they have to restart Visual Studio 2010 in order to get my query changes. Is there anyway of forcing an update on team queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right-click on your Team Project in Team Explorer you 'll see the 'refresh' option. This should do.
 'Refresh' is also available in Work Item level.